# ADT 21 and library projects

Tags: android, kml, gpx

Yesterday I updated adt to v 21. Today, after minor corrections I rebuild and start project, but it crashes. In my project i use few library progects. ActionbarSherlock is one of them. Logcat says "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable at..."

Answer (score 1):

The solution in my case was different though.

We need to make sure that in the library projects there aren't projects with the same package name.

If 2 library projects have the same package name, the build process will not generate R for any of them. Changing the package name of one of them (so both libraries have different package names) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After few minutes of looking to logcat and head scratching i noticed, that R classes for library projects hasn't been generated in my project /gen folder. Why? It's a secret for me.

I just rebuilded library projects, than my - it solves the problem.

From adt release notes:

> Updated the build to generate R resource classes for library projects with only the IDs needed by the libraries, reducing the risk of hitting DEX file limits for fields and methods.

It seems adt just ignore library projects build under the version prior v21